# How to clean up instances of a class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of the Student class which every time I press a button I add new instances of the Student class to this List. However, every time I press the button, the classes are incrementing, when it should only go to the values that I selected.
My question is, how can I clear all items from this List _studentsTest ?

```dart
 List<Student>? _studentsTest = []; //my class

//when I press the button I do this
onConfirm: (results) {
        setState(() {
          _studentsTest = results.cast<Student>();
        });
      }
```

This image shows that each line when I click on the button increments an instance of the class, but what I imagine should happen is that there will always be only one class.

[image]

Comment: use _studentsTest.clear() before setState

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you've shown.  Where do you actually add elements to the `List`?  Where does `results` come from?  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [`.clear()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/List/clear.html) method on your list `_studentsTest`:

> Removes all objects from this list; the length of the list becomes zero.

```dart
List<Student>? _studentsTest = [];
  
  onConfirm: (results) {
    _studentsTest.clear();
    setState(() {
      _studentsTest = results.cast<Student>();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I doubt that this will matter since `_studentsTest` will be clobbered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use `_studentsTest.clear()` before

```
     onConfirm: (results) {
        setState(() {
          _studentsTest.clear();
          _studentsTest = results.cast<Student>();
        });
      }
```

Comment: I doubt that this will matter since `_studentsTest` will be clobbered anyway.